# Iterating over an array and inserting an element at index

Tags: python, arrays, vector, insert

I have to implement the Vector ADT in python. All other methods work but I am stuck on the implementation of insert and remove.

**insert(index, element)**: Inserts the given element into the vector at position index. The elements at and following the given position are shifted down to make room for the new item. The index must be within the valid range and the vector can not be full. If index is one position beyond the end of the vector, the item is appended onto the vector.

**remove(index)**: Removes the element at position index from the vector. The removed element is returned. All elements following the removed element are shifted down one position to close the gap resulting from the removed element.

My code:

```
from ezarrays import Array

class Vector :
   # Creates an empty vector instance.

def __init__(self) :

   self._theArray = Array( 2 )
   self._capacity = 2
   self._numItems = 0

   # Returns the number of elements in the vector.
def __len__(self):
   return self._numItems

   # Returns the element at the given index position.

def __getitem__(self, index) :
    assert index >= 0 and index < self._numItems, "Index out of range."
    return self._theArray[index]

   # Stores the given element at the given index position. 
  def __setitem__(self, index, element) :
     assert index >= 0 and index <= self._numItems, "Index out of range."
     if index == self._numItems :
       self.append(element)
    else :
      self._theArray[index] = element

   # Returns a string representation of the vector in the form: [e1, e2 ...]
  def __repr__(self) :
    if self._numItems == 0 :
      return "[]"
    else :
      result = ""
      i = 0
      while i < self._numItems - 1 :
        result = result + str(self._theArray[i]) + ", "
        i = i + 1

      result = result + str(self._theArray[i])
      return "[" + result + "]"

   # Appends the given element to the end of the vector.
  def append(self, element) :
    if self._numItems == self._capacity :
       self._expandArray()
    index = self._numItems
    self._theArray[index] = element
    self._numItems = self._numItems + 1

  # Returns a Boolean indicating if the given element is in the vector.
  def __contains__(self, element) :
    for i in range(self._numItems):
      if self._theArray[i] == element:
        return True
    return False

   # Returns the position index within the vector that contains the given element
   def index(self, element) :
     assert element in self, "The element must be in the list."
     for i in range(self._numItems) :
       index = self._theArray[i]
       if index == element :
        return i

  # Inserts the given element into the vector at position index     
   def insert(self, index, element) :
     assert index >= 0 and index <= self._numItems, "Index out of range."
     if self._numItems == self._capacity:
       self._expandArray()
     i=0
     while i < len(self._theArray):
         element = self._theArray[i] 
        do_action(element)
        if check(element):
             del self.-_theArray[i]
        else:
            i+=1    

  # Removes the element at position index from the vector. 
  def remove(self, index) :
    pass

  # Removes all elements from the vector resulting in an empty vector   
   def clear(self) :
     self.theArray = Array(2)
     self._capacity = 2
     self._numItems = 0

  # expands the array by expanding capacity and making a new array
  def _expandArray(self) :
    newCapacity = self._capacity * 2
    newArray = Array( newCapacity )
    for i in range (len(self._theArray)):
      newArray[i] = self._theArray[i]
    self._theArray = newArray
```

The implementation of ezarrays (which is the array)
    import ctypes

```
class Array :
   # Creates an array with size elements.
  def __init__( self, size ):               
    assert size > 0, "Array size must be > 0"
    self._size = size    

     # Create the array structure using the ctypes module.
    PyArrayType = ctypes.py_object * size          
    self._elements = PyArrayType()

     # Initialize each element.
    self.clear(None)                        

   # Returns the size of the array.
  def __len__( self ):
    return self._size

   # Gets the contents of the index element.
  def __getitem__( self, index ):                  
    assert index >= 0 and index < len(self), "Array subscript out of range"
    return self._elements[ index ]

   # Puts the value in the array element at index position.
  def __setitem__( self, index, value ):
    assert index >= 0 and index < len(self), "Array subscript out of range"
    self._elements[ index ] = value                 

   # Clears the array by setting each element to the given value.
   def clear( self, value ) :
    for i in range(len(self)) :
      self._elements[i] = value


# Implementation of the Array2D ADT using an array of arrays. 
class Array2D :  
   # Creates a 2-D array of size numRows x numCols.
  def __init__( self, numRows, numCols ):
     # Create a 1-D array to store an array reference for each row.
    self._theRows = Array(numRows)

     # Create the 1-D arrays for each row of the 2-D array.
    for i in range( numRows ) :
      self._theRows[i] = Array(numCols)

   # Returns the number of rows in the 2-d array.
  def numRows( self ):
    return len( self._theRows )

   # Returns the number of columns in the 2-d array.
  def numCols( self ):
    return len( self._theRows[0] )

   # Clears the array by setting every element to the given value.
  def clear( self, value ):
    for row in range(len(self._theRows)) :
      self._theRows[row].clear(value)

   # Get the contents of the element at position [i, j]
  def __getitem__( self, ndxTuple ):                                
    assert len(ndxTuple) == 2, "Invalid number of array subscripts." 
    row = ndxTuple[0]
    col = ndxTuple[1]
    assert row >= 0 and row < self.numRows() \
       and col >= 0 and col < self.numCols(), \
           "Array subscript out of range."
    the1dArray = self._theRows[row]
    return the1dArray[col]                       

   # Set the contents of the element at position [i,j] to value.
  def __setitem__( self, ndxTuple, value ):
     assert len(ndxTuple) == 2, "Invalid number of array subscripts."    
     row = ndxTuple[0]
     col = ndxTuple[1]
     assert row >= 0 and row < self.numRows() \
       and col >= 0 and col < self.numCols(), \
           "Array subscript out of range."
    the1dArray = self._theRows[row]
    the1dArray[col] = value
```

Comment: What is `ezarrays`, I can't find that module!? And why are you not using any existing libraries for this?

Comment: ezarrays is a module that we use for python that implements the "behind the scenes" work. It is given to us by our teacher

Comment: You state that you're stuck with the insert and remove function but I see an insert function implemented?

Comment: It doesn't work. That's just what I have at this moment

Comment: typo in the code  `del self.-_theArray[i]`      instead of:       `del self._theArray[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Okay since I don't have the module you're using I can't really test the code but here is my idea:

```
def remove(self, idx):
    elem = self._theArray[idx]
    new_array = Array(self._capacity-1)

    for i in range(0, self._numItems):
        if i != idx:
            new_array.append(self._theArray[i])

    self._theArray = new_array
    return elem

def insert(self, index, element) :
    assert index >= 0 and index <= self._numItems, "Index out of range."
    if self._numItems == self._capacity:
        self._expandArray()

    for i in reversed(range(index, self._numItems)):
        self._theArray[i+1] = self._theArray[i]

    self._theArray[index] = element
```

Comment: Is there a way for it not to return None when I remove [1] in an array of 3 elements? When I ran the return I recieved: The new vector:  [20, 40, None]. The test code I used was: vector1.remove(1)
print("The new vector: ", vector1)

Comment: What data structure is Array?

Comment: can you just not have an else?

Comment: it is similar to what python calls a list but you can't implement as much with it

Comment: if you remove the `else` then the last element will remain where it is

Comment: Can you share the implementation of Array?

Comment: I need it to remove an element at a specific index. So in my test case I say vector1.remove(1) so I am trying to remove the element at index 1. and yes I can. I can add it to the code above

Comment: When you remove an element is the total capacity of the Array supposed to stay the same or also be reduced by 1?

Comment: it needs to reduce by 1

Comment: The error I am recieving from the remove method.                                         for i in self._numItems:
builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Updated the code, this is just to give you an idea of how to do it, since it's a school project, I'm not so eager to solve it all for you

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you though.